GE/Proficy Historian - add a tag with IHUAPI
I do quite a few things with the IHUAPI like Migrate data from one Historian to another, query data into clients, etc.  Now I am trying to create a tag, but cannot seem to figure it out.  The only thing I see in the IHUAPI is the following:
[DllImport(DLLNAME, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall, EntryPoint = "ihuTagAdd@4")]
public static extern ihuErrorCode ihuTagAdd(int serverhandle);

How would I use that to add a tag when serverhandle is the only parameter?  I'm sure there is a way to do this, but I have been struggling to figure it out.

I figured out how to do this:
            //create a new tag
            IHUAPI.ihuTagClearProperties();
            IHUAPI.ihuTagSetNumericProperty(ihuTagProperties.DataType, (double)type);
            IHUAPI.ihuTagSetStringProperty(ihuTagProperties.Tagname, TagName);
            IHUAPI.ihuTagSetStringProperty(ihuTagProperties.Description, "iHUAPI Generated Tag");


            ihuErrorCode result = IHUAPI.ihuTagAdd(handle);

It is an odd way to do it, but that works.
